# NoSuchMethodError in org.codehaus.jackson.JsonNode.asText() with Jackson

Tags: java, json, rest, jackson

I'm starting to learn REST services and I am trying to implent a REST client that excute a get method, this method returns a Json Object like this

```
{"accounts":[],"dateTime":"2020-01-31T14:06:51.386Z","status":{"statusCode":"404","statusDesc":"No hay resultados para la consulta."}}
```

So I did it in my Eclipse version 2019-03 (4.11.0) and it worked fine. Then I generated a executable file that imports the jars jackson-core-lgpl-1.9.13.jar and jackson-mapper-lgpl-1.9.13.jar that I use in my Eclipse. Then I tried it in development environment, I recieved the Json Object but when I tried to extract the tag statusCode received this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonNode.asText()Ljava/lang/String;
```

In this line

```
ResponseCode responseCode = FilterSettings
                .getFilterCodeIsoToB24(infoAccounts.getStatus().path("statusCode").asText(), allCodesIsoToB24);
```

I don't understand why in Eclipse works fine but in development enviroment not. I check the class path and the jar files are in. I put here the class that define my Json Object.

```
package po.real.iso.utils;


import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonNode;

public class JsonAccounts {
private String accounts[];
private String dateTime;
private JsonNode status;

public JsonAccounts() {
    //default constructor
}

/**
 * @return the account
 */
public String[] getAccounts() {
    return accounts;
}

/**
 * @param accounts the accounts to set
 */
public void setAccounts(String accounts[]) {
    this.accounts = accounts;
}

/**
 * @return the dateTime
 */
public String getDateTime() {
    return dateTime;
}

/**
 * @param dateTime the sessionValues to set
 */
public void setDateTime(String dateTime) {
    this.dateTime = dateTime;
}

/**
 * @return the status
 */
public JsonNode getStatus() {
    return status;
}

/**
 * @param status the status to set
 */
public void setStatus(JsonNode status) {
    this.status = status;
}


}
```

The development environment has installed

- Java 8 Update 211 version 8.0.2110.12
- Java SE Development Kit Update 8 171 8.0.1710.11

But on my computer, I have installed the following

- Java 8 Update 131 version 8.0.1310.11
- Java 8 Update 201 version 8.0.2010.9
- Java SE Development Kit Update 8 131 8.0.1310.11.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Check your generated jar inside and look if those dependencies where correctly included.

Comment: The problem is not your JsonAccounts, but rather your consuming application, which can't resolve the dependency.

Comment: It more a matter of jackson version rather than a JDK version. Check in your development environment if fetch the jackson dependecy. Also, if jackson depencedy is fetched check if you have the same version in the two environments (Eclipse and dev)

Comment: Thanks, I have checked the jars and are the same on both Eclipse and dev. But something intesant happens, the dependency is resolved, because the application can use the ObjectMapper to catch the JsonObject and indeed found the class JsonNode but doesn't find the method asText() inside.